# Чи доречне використання дієприслівників минулого часу недоконаного виду в сучасній українській мові?

Tags: граматика

Дано 2 речення:

1. Я писав цей вірш, думаючи про тебе.
2. Я писав цей вірш, думавши про тебе.

Хоча обидва речення правильні з граматичної точки зору, **чи друге — доречне у сучасній українській мові?**

Наскільки я розумію, попри те, що:

> В  укр. мові  найвиразнішою  морфологічною  дієсл. ознакою  Д. [дієприслівника]  є  категорія  виду.  Значення  часу  в них  морфологічно  нейтралізоване.

Дієприслівники все ж повинні узгоджуватись у часі з дієсловом у реченні, до якого вони відносяться.

Але моя вчителька з української мови сказала, що наразі в нашій мові відходять від використання дієприслівників минулого часу недоконаного виду і доречно використовувати дієприслівники теперішнього часу недоконаного виду, не зважаючи на час дієслова, до якого вони відносяться. Мені також ріже вухо другий варіант.

> Залежно  від  виду  вихідного  дієслова  розрізняють Д. [дієприслівники]  недоконаного  (кажучи,  плачучи,  читаючи, мучачи,  просячи,  читавши,  прохавши)  і  доконаного  (грюкнувши,  принісши,  прочитавши) виду.
> Перші  утворюються  від  основи  теп.  ч. (форми  3-ї  ос.  мн.)  за  допомогою  суфіксів  —  -учи (-ючи)  та  -ачи  (-ячи)  і  рідше  від  основи  мин. ч.  (форми  чол.  р.  одн.)  за  допомогою  суфікса -ши:  бер-уть  >  бер-учи,  клен-уть  >  клен-учи, працку-уть  >  працюі-учи,  кол-ють  >  кол-ючи,
> крич-ать  >  крич-ачи,  мол-ять  >  мол-ячи;  біг  > біг-ши,  ніс  >  ніс-ши,  брав  >  брав-ши.
> Другі  — від  основи  мин.  ч.  за  допомогою  суфікса  -ши: довершив  >  довершив-ши,  зробив  >  зробив-ши, гримнув  >  гримнув-ши,  прибіг  >  прибіг-ши.

Звідси ж випливає `і  рідше  від  основи  мин. ч.  (форми  чол.  р.  одн.)  за  допомогою  суфікса -ши`, що хоч і рідко, але такі дієприслівники вживаються.

Якщо про дієприкметники на -чий в енциклопедії напряму пояснюється, чому вони наразі маловживані й краще їх не використовувати, то про дієприслівники минулого часу недоконаного виду таке не пишеться:

> Д. [дієприкметник]  на  -чий  поширені  мало,  тому  що народнорозм.  мова,  яка  лягла  в  основу  нової
> укр.  літ.  мови,  майже  не  знала  їх  (як  книжних форм  давньорус.  походження).  У мові  20  ст., особливо  в  період  30-х  —  80-х  рр.,  вони  дещо активізувалися,  зокрема  у  зв’язку  з  творенням н.-т.  термінів  (крокуючий  екскаватор,  блукаючий нерв),  але  ост.  часом  їх  відповідність  нормам  укр.  мови  дедалі  більше  піддається  сумнівам.

Усі цитати наведені з:

> Українська мова: Енциклопедія / НАН України, Інститут мовознавства ім. О. О. Потебні, Інститут української мови; редкол.: В. М. Русанівський (співголова), О. О. Тараненко (співголова), М. П. Зяблюк та ін. — 2-ге вид., випр. і доп. — К. : Вид-во «Укр. енцикл.» ім. М. П. Бажана, 2004. — 824 с. : іл. — ISBN 966-7492-19-2.

Comment: Загалом, дієприслівник не притаманний українській мові. Його можна легко позбавитись, якщо складнопідрядне речення перетворити на два простих. Та коли є необхідність вжити Д., орієнтуйтесь на його роль в реченні https://uk.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%96%D1%94%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA
1-ий приклад звучить ок. 2-ий я б записав так: «Подумавши про тебе, я написав цей вірш.»

Comment: Тобто зробили б його доконаного виду, зрозуміла, дякую! А також дякую за посилання. В вікіпедії, до речі, також наведений приклад використання Д. Недок. В. Мин. Ч., хоча на початку статті нема питання, на яке б він відповідав - лише що роблячи? і що зробивши?

Comment: Дієприслівники недоконаного виду минулого часу виражають додаткову дію, що відбувалася в минулому одночасно з основною (відповідає на питання що робивши?): Слухавши вірші про кохання, він завжди згадував її (він одночасно слухав і згадував).

Comment: Так, я розумію, питання про те, чи доречні вони у сучасній мові чи ми від них відходимо. Я розумію, що це валідна граматична форма. Так само як `рахуючий` теж валідна, хоча на рахунок цього я знайшла джерала з підтвердженнями, що українській мові такі словотвори не притаманні.